# How to get category levels via multi-dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

How to get count of category levels dynamically. This is a PHP array and this can be change when user change the menu structure but for the time being this is a structure i just wanted to know the main category that how many levels of child category inside the mail category and the main category is "Brands". Here is my array structure.

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idCategory] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                [category] => Brands
                [slug] => brands
                [description] => 
                [image] => 
                [parentCategory] => 
                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                [date] => 2017-06-07 14:58:31
            )

        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [idCategory] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                [category] => Apparel
                                [slug] => apparel
                                [description] => 
                                [image] => 
                                [parentCategory] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                [date] => 2017-06-07 14:58:51
                            )

                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => 3681265e-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [idCategory] => 3681265e-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [category] => Adidas
                                                [slug] => adidas
                                                [description] => 
                                                [image] => 
                                                [parentCategory] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                                [date] => 2017-06-07 14:59:59
                                            )

                                        [children] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => 3f211015-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [idCategory] => 3f211015-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [category] => Columbia
                                                [slug] => columbia
                                                [description] => 
                                                [image] => 
                                                [parentCategory] => 0ded5b28-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                                [date] => 2017-06-07 15:00:14
                                            )

                                        [children] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [idCategory] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                [category] => Footwear
                                [slug] => footwear
                                [description] => 
                                [image] => 
                                [parentCategory] => 01e3f447-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                [date] => 2017-06-07 14:59:11
                            )

                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => 49becbc8-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [idCategory] => 49becbc8-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [category] => Polo
                                                [slug] => polo
                                                [description] => 
                                                [image] => 
                                                [parentCategory] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                                [date] => 2017-06-07 15:00:31
                                            )

                                        [children] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => 4e647bee-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                        [nodeInfo] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [idCategory] => 4e647bee-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [category] => Nike
                                                [slug] => nike
                                                [description] => 
                                                [image] => 
                                                [parentCategory] => 1988d10a-4b81-11e7-a858-b8763f541038
                                                [idStatus] => e9d3b949-1301-11e7-a9b8-b8763f541038
                                                [date] => 2017-06-07 15:00:39
                                            )

                                        [children] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: your question is not clear about exactly what you are expecting.

Comment: Look my array structure and you will see the main array is Brands and the level is (1) and inside Brands->Apparels which level is (2) and inside Brands->Apparels->Adidas which level is (3) this is what exactly i want. i wanted to know the levels of child category inside the mail category.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this recursively:

```
function  countChildren($array) {
       $children = 0;
       if (isset($array["children"]) {
            $children = count($array["children"]);
            foreach ($array["children"] as $subarray) {
               $children += countChildren($subarray);
            }
        } 
        return $children;          
}
```

To just count the levels you can do:

```
function  countChildrenLevels($array) {
       $children = 0;
       if (isset($array["children"]) {                
            $sublevels = [];
            foreach ($array["children"] as $subarray) {
               $sublevels[] = countChildren($subarray);
            }
            $children = 1 + max($sublevels);
        } 
        return $children;          
}
```

Comment: @MuazzamAli As soon answer helps your issue to be solved you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) as correct one.